# How can I make a copy of object via Reflection API?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create copy of object via `Reflection API`. Here is my code:

```
private <T> T copy(T entity) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    Field[] retrievedFields = entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : retrievedFields) {
        fields.add(field);
    }
    T newEntity = (T) entity.getClass().newInstance();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(newEntity, field.get(entity));
    }
    return newEntity;
}
```

But I don't know how to get values of fields.

Comment: There's a `set`. Wouldn't there be a `get`? Have you looked at the javadoc?

Comment: There is `get(Object)` method. Object is a field?

Comment: Please read the javadoc. If `Object` is the field and `field` is the field, what's the point? (`Object` is the object whose field's value you want to get.)

Comment: I updated code in my question. Is it correct now?

Comment: It says, "Returns the value of the field represented by this Field, on the specified object." and "Parameters:
obj - object from which the represented field's value is to be extracted"

Comment: Why are you adding the `Field` objects to a `List`? In any case, no, your code won't get parent class fields. The object will potentially not be fully copied.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Um... what's this about 'getting parent class fields'?

Comment: @bcsb1001 `getDeclaredFields` returns the fields declared in the class represented by _this_ `Class` object. That is, it doesn't return inherited fields.

Comment: Oh. So there's another one problem.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Is there any way to copy the fields of parent classes as well?

Comment: @Alex you could create a recursive method using `entity.getClass().getSuperclass()`.

Comment: Ok, and how should I stop recursion invocation? Last parent returns `null`?

Comment: In fact my current code returns different hashCodes for copy and origin instance. So maybe it works fine?

Comment: @Alex By recursion, I am talking about something similar to the accepted answer, but recursively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use superClass to get superClass. "Object" will be superClass of all class. SuperClass of Object is null. Either you can check for "Object" or null for terminating condition. Anyhow declaredFields for Object wont return anything.

```
private <T> T copy(T entity) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class<?> clazz = entity.getClass();
    T newEntity = (T) entity.getClass().newInstance();

    while (clazz != null) {
        copyFields(entity, newEntity, clazz);
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }

    return newEntity;
}

private <T> T copyFields(T entity, T newEntity, Class<?> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        fields.add(field);
    }
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(newEntity, field.get(entity));
    }
    return newEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work for a deep clone.
may be consider this to start :

```
private Object copy(Object entity) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class<?> clazz = entity.getClass();
    LOG.debug("Clazz="+clazz);
    Object newEntity = clazz.newInstance();

    while (clazz != null) {
        copyFields(entity, newEntity, clazz);
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return newEntity;
}
private void copyFields(Object entity, Object newEntity, Class<?> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        fields.add(field);
    }
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        LOG.debug("Field name="+field.getName());
        LOG.debug("Field type="+field.getType());
        if (!field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
            entity = copy(field.getType().newInstance());
        } else field.set(newEntity, field.get(entity));
    }
}
```